# string to dropdownlist as items

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, arraylist

On ASP.net webform I'm trying populate dropdownlist with items that received as a sting from the server but insted of idividual items it shows as text.

How can I make the retrived string to be added to dropdownlist as items ?

Button click code:

```
protected void btnSend_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        server.Connect(ipep);
        NetworkStream stream = new NetworkStream(server);
        Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("GU");
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        data = new Byte[256];
        Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        ResponseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);

        DropDownList1.Items.Add(ResponseData);

        server.Close();
    }
```

On other side Powershell server will complete the function and response with:

```
function GU
{
$global:rresult = @("test1" , "test2" , "test3")
}
```

And Unfortunately the result is:
[DropDownListAsString](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whwKp.jpg)

Tried to `.Split(',')` and other things but nothing worked.
Any idea how could I add `"test1" , "test2" , "test3"` as separate items ?

Comment: If there are not comma's in the original Response string but spaces..  then try `string.Split(" ")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your `ResponseData` ends up being `"test1 test2 test3"`.

Now, you want to tokenize your string into individual tokens and we can see that your string is delimited by space. So, we can tokenize it using `ResponseData.Split(' ')` to get the tokens.

```
ResponseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
string[] tokens = ResponseData.Split(' ');
foreach (string token in tokens)
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(token);
```

Comment: `ResponseData.Split(" ")` didn't work and had to use `ResponseData.Split(' ');`  . Now it's working perfectly.  Thanks